# Can a rune knight give runes to allies?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, rune-knight

It doesn't disallow the rune knight from putting runes on ally's equipment, or giving inscribed equipment to allies, but there's also the difference of language from Artificer infusions, with infusions, it refers to "the wearer," and rune knight refers to "you." So it seems that it wouldn't work.

Can a rune knight inscribe allies' equipment and have them benefit from the runes?

Answer (score 10):

### It can only be your gear and only you benefit

The description of the primary Rune Carver feature says:

> You can use magic runes to enhance **your** gear

I admit that the wording that comes later merely says you can choose a number of objects equal to the runes you know, without stating it can only be your equipment. But the description of each individual rune makes it clear that only you can use the rune or benefit from it anyway.

For example, the Fire Rune says:

> While wearing or carrying an object inscribed with this rune, **your**
> proficiency bonus is doubled...

and then:

> In addition, when **you** hit a creature with an attack using a weapon,
> **you** can invoke the rune to summon fiery shackles

There is an argument that the previously mentioned paragraphs can be taken separately, in which case you could put a rune on somebody else's weapon which would prevent you benefitting from the first aspect (the proficiency bonus) but could still activate the rune when you hit with your weapon (even though the rune is on somebody else's weapon)...but that would be rather pointless! (And doesn't seem to be the intent).

Comment: Maybe emphasize that using the runes is a class feature that only the rune knight has.

Comment: I dunno about the first point though. If I enhance my sword, get KO'd, and the Barbarian picks it up and swings with it, it's still *my* sword.

Comment: @RevenantBacon Technically true, but the wording of the runes still says _your_ proficiency bonus is double or _you_ can activate the rune and so on. Not much use when you're KO-ed. So, as far as the Barbarian is concerned they are merely using a sword with a pretty design on it!

Comment: Personally, I think it's ambiguous. The intent is clearly for them to enchant their equipment, but I don't see anything preventing them from giving it away afterwards, and all the runes are worded as "While wearing or carrying an item with this rune, you...", which seems ambiguous whether "you" is referring to the Rune Knight or to the person wearing or carrying the item.